# Laravel validation doesn't work with google recaptcha

Tags: laravel, validation, session, laravel-blade, recaptcha

Without google recaptcha, standard Laravel validation on the registration form works fine. I get error messages under each field:

```
 <form name="registerForm" id="registerForm" method="post" action="{{route("register")}}">
        @csrf
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="name" class="form-label">Имя</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value="{{old("name")}}" placeholder="Введите Имя">
            @error('name')
            {{$message}}
            <div class="form-text">
                123123
                {{$message}}
            </div>
            @enderror
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="username" class="form-label">Логин</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="{{old("username")}}" placeholder="Придумайте Логин">
            @error('username')
            <div class="form-text">
                {{$message}}
            </div>
            @enderror
        </div>
...
```

Laravel backend code:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        "name" => 'required|max:255',
        "username" => ['required', 'max:255', Rule::unique("users", "username")],
        "email" => ['required', 'email', 'max:255', Rule::unique("users", "email")],
        "password" => 'required|confirmed',
    ]);
...
```

Pretty standard. But when I add

```
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

into the **head** section, and

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Le...."></div>
```

into the **form**, I stop getting error messages about empty fields. Logs are empty. I tried to debug it like this:

```
        @if ($errors->any())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Still see no result. If I remove the recaptcha, everything will work again. Do you have any thoughts on why it's happening?